# Infragistics - XamDocManager - Limit ContentPanes width in unpinned state

Tags: wpf, xaml, infragistics

I am using XamDocManager for one of my WPF application. The XamDocManager has two ContentPanes within TabGroupPane as shown in the below XAML.

```
<igDock:XamDockManager Name="MyXamDM">
<igDock:XamDockManager.Panes>                
    <igDock:SplitPane Name="Sp1" SplitterOrientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              igDock:XamDockManager.InitialLocation="DockedLeft" MaxWidth="100">
        <igDock:TabGroupPane MaxWidth="100">
            <igDock:ContentPane Header="Top" Content="Top" 
                     Name="Cp1"/>
            <igDock:ContentPane Header="Bottom" Content="Bottom" 
                    Name="Cp2" />
        </igDock:TabGroupPane>
    </igDock:SplitPane>
</igDock:XamDockManager.Panes>
```

I have MaxWidth attribute set to 100 in TabGroupPane and SplitPane.

During run-time I checked two scenarios:

**Scenario 1:** Pin the contentpanes and increase its width more than 100px

**Scenario 2:** Unpin the contentpanes and increase its width more than 100px

Scenario 1 works fine, but Scenario 2 failed. I am able to increase the panes width more than 100px when the contentpanes are unpinned. MaxWidth property does not take effect when the contentpanes are unpinned.

Irrespective of whether contentpanes are pinned or unpinned I need to limit its width to 100px.

Comment: lol.... First, let me preface this with "I'm sorry you chose to use the XamDocManager"... Okay, now that we've got that done... Have you tried subclassing PaneToolWindow and hard coding the max width?

Comment: thanks. Not yet tried subclassing panetoolwindow. Any related links or samples will be helpful.

Comment: The only example I know that exists belongs to my company because I wrote it haha. I can't post it at all. What I can tell you though is subclassing it and setting that property on it will probably work

Comment: After you subclass it you also subclass xamdockmanager and override OnPaneToolWindowCreated. Then return yours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to control the width of unpinned contentpane by setting MaxWidth property of UnpinnedTabFlyout.

```
   <igDock:XamDockManager.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type igDock:UnpinnedTabFlyout}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=Side}" Value="Left">
                        <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="100"/>                            
                    </DataTrigger>                        
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>            
    </igDock:XamDockManager.Resources>
```

Details on UnpinnedTabFlyout is available [here](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WPF/2016.1/CLR4.0/html/InfragisticsWPF4.DockManager.v16.1~Infragistics.Windows.DockManager.UnpinnedTabFlyout.html).